# Convert contents of an image into an ASCII image

Tags: java, ascii-art

I've stored the grayscale of an image into a double array and now i need to do the following task but I'm not sure where to begin:

```
The contents of the image in <infile> will be converted into an ASCII image. 
Use the following (approximate!) grayscale-to-character mappings. You are free
to adjust the numeric ranges a little bit in order to make programming easier:
 o 0 to 25:‘M’
 o 26 to 50:‘$’
 o 51 to 76:‘o’
 o 77 to 102:‘|’
 o 103 to 127: ‘*’
 o 128 to 152: ‘:’
 o 153 to 178: ‘=’
 o 179 to 204: ‘\’’ (note the escape character before the single-quote)
 o 205 to 230: ‘.’
 o 231 to 255: ‘ ’ (i.e., a single space)
```

Comment: First you need to reduce the pixels down to a manageable number by averaging adjacent pixels into one.  Then the simplest is to build an array of 256 characters with the above values in the indicated ranges, then just "translate" each row of averaged pixels into a character by indexing that character array.  Pretty basic stuff -- averaging groups of pixels together probably requires the most thought.

Comment: (Or you could do it the old-fashioned way and keypunch the image out on cards.)

Comment: see **#1 Linearly distributed intensity character map** in  [Image to ASCII art conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32987834/2521214) its the same approach (the simplest one)

Answer (score 2):

I found this code that can help you to convert an image to an AsciiArt. Source: [AsciiArt From Image](https://gist.github.com/shmert/3859200)

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

/*Copyright (c) 2011 Aravind Rao
Modifications by Sam Barnum, 360Works 2012
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
 * use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons
 * to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO
 * THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT,
 * TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
*/

public final class ASCII {
    boolean negative;

    public ASCII() {
        this(false);
    }

    public ASCII(final boolean negative) {
        this.negative = negative;
    }

    public String convert(final BufferedImage image) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((image.getWidth() + 1) * image.getHeight());
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            if (sb.length() != 0) sb.append("\n");
            for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
                Color pixelColor = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
                double gValue = (double) pixelColor.getRed() * 0.2989 + (double) pixelColor.getBlue() * 0.5870 + (double) pixelColor.getGreen() * 0.1140;
                final char s = negative ? returnStrNeg(gValue) : returnStrPos(gValue);
                sb.append(s);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new string and assign to it a string based on the grayscale value.
     * If the grayscale value is very high, the pixel is very bright and assign characters
     * such as . and , that do not appear very dark. If the grayscale value is very lowm the pixel is very dark,
     * assign characters such as # and @ which appear very dark.
     *
     * @param g grayscale
     * @return char
     */
    private char returnStrPos(double g)//takes the grayscale value as parameter
    {
        final char str;

        if (g >= 230.0) {
            str = ' ';
        } else if (g >= 200.0) {
            str = '.';
        } else if (g >= 180.0) {
            str = '*';
        } else if (g >= 160.0) {
            str = ':';
        } else if (g >= 130.0) {
            str = 'o';
        } else if (g >= 100.0) {
            str = '&';
        } else if (g >= 70.0) {
            str = '8';
        } else if (g >= 50.0) {
            str = '#';
        } else {
            str = '@';
        }
        return str; // return the character

    }

    /**
     * Same method as above, except it reverses the darkness of the pixel. A dark pixel is given a light character and vice versa.
     *
     * @param g grayscale
     * @return char
     */
    private char returnStrNeg(double g) {
        final char str;

        if (g >= 230.0) {
            str = '@';
        } else if (g >= 200.0) {
            str = '#';
        } else if (g >= 180.0) {
            str = '8';
        } else if (g >= 160.0) {
            str = '&';
        } else if (g >= 130.0) {
            str = 'o';
        } else if (g >= 100.0) {
            str = ':';
        } else if (g >= 70.0) {
            str = '*';
        } else if (g >= 50.0) {
            str = '.';
        } else {
            str = ' ';
        }
        return str;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images", "jpg", "gif", "png"));
                while (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        File f = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);
                        if (image == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(f + " is not a valid image.");
                        final String ascii = new ASCII().convert(image);
                        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(ascii, image.getHeight(), image.getWidth());
                        textArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 5));
                        textArea.setEditable(false);
                        final JDialog dialog = new JOptionPane(new JScrollPane(textArea), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE).createDialog(ASCII.class.getName());
                        dialog.setResizable(true);
                        dialog.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Source: [AsciiArt From Image](https://gist.github.com/shmert/3859200)

Hope it helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you keeping some values in the array? You can do that by if or switch statements.

```
public char[][] transform(int[][] gray)
{
int row = gray[0].length;
int column = gray[1].length;
char[][] mapedImage = new char[row][column];
for (int i= 0; i < row ;i++)
{
     for(int k = 0; k < column ;k++)
     {
     if(0<gray[i][k]<25)
        char[i][k] = 'M';
     .
     .
     .

     }
}
return mapedImage;
}
```

Comment: A typical image will be at least 500x300.  One needs to get that down to about 100x60 to be able to print the image.