# Image to ASCII art conversion

Tags: c++, image-processing, bitmap, 2d, ascii-art

## Prologue

This subject pops up here on Stack Overflow from time to time, but it is removed usually because of being a poorly written question. I saw many such questions and then silence from the **OP** (usual low rep) when additional information is requested. From time to time if the input is good enough for me I decide to respond with an answer and it usually gets a few up-votes per day while active, but then after a few weeks the question gets removed/deleted and all starts from the beginning. So I decided to write this **Q&A** so I can reference such questions directly without rewriting the answer over and over again …

Another reason is also this [meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307481/bulletpoints-everywhere) targeted at me so if you got additional input, feel free to comment.

## Question

How can I convert a bitmap image to **ASCII art** using **C++**?

Some constraints:

- gray scale images
- using mono-spaced fonts
- keeping it simple (not using too advanced stuff for beginner level programmers)

Here is a related Wikipedia page [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art#Types_and_styles) (thanks to @RogerRowland).

Here similar [maze to ASCII Art conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63194022/2521214) Q&A.

Comment: Using [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) as a reference, can you clarify to which type of ASCII art you are referring? It sounds to me like "Image to text conversion" which is a "simple" look-up from grayscale pixels to corresponding text character, so I'm wondering if you mean something different. It sounds like you're going to answer it yourself anyway though .....

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26347985/2564301

Comment: @RogerRowland both simple (only grayscale intensity based) and more advanced taking into account also shape of characters (but still simple enough)

Comment: While your work is great, I certainly would appreciate a selection of samples that are a bit more SFW.

Comment: @TimCastelijns If you read the prologue then you can see this is not the first time such type of answer was requested (and most voters from start where familiar with few previous questions related so the rest just voted accordingly), As this is **Q&A** not just **Q** I did not  waste too much time with the **Q** part (which is fault on my side I admit) have added few restrictions to the question if you got a better ones feel free to edit.

Comment: @Spektre I removed it a while back

Comment: @TimCastelijns I saw but your point stands anyway.

Comment: @Spektre My problem was only with the question. A question should not need a prologue. I do think the Q&A here is very useful. But I view questions and answers seperately and if you had not been able to answer this yourself, nobody else would have done it because it's just way too big a task. I have mixed feelings about this so I figured I'd better leave it alone.

Comment: @TimCastelijns this is simple in comparison to real complicated things I deal with in my work. But for beginner programmers this could get overwhelming as they usually lack background knowledge, experience and discipline.

Comment: @kmote How about just being respectful to others?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

There are more approaches for image to ASCII art conversion which are mostly based on using **mono-spaced fonts**. For simplicity, I stick only to basics:

**Pixel/area intensity based (shading)**

This approach handles each pixel of an area of pixels as a single dot. The idea is to compute the average gray scale intensity of this dot and then replace it with character with close enough intensity to the computed one. For that we need some list of usable characters, each with a precomputed intensity. Let's call it a character `map`. To choose more quickly which character is the best for which intensity, there are two ways:

1. **Linearly distributed intensity character map**

   So we use only characters which have an intensity difference with the same step. In other words, when sorted ascending then:

   ```
    intensity_of(map[i])=intensity_of(map[i-1])+constant;
   ```

   Also when our character `map` is sorted then we can compute the character directly from intensity (no search needed)

   ```
    character = map[intensity_of(dot)/constant];
   ```
2. **Arbitrary distributed intensity character map**

   So we have array of usable characters and their intensities. We need to find intensity closest to the `intensity_of(dot)` So again if we sorted the `map[]`, we can use binary search, otherwise we need an `O(n)` search minimum distance loop or `O(1)` dictionary. Sometimes for simplicity, the character `map[]` can be handled as linearly distributed, causing a slight gamma distortion, usually unseen in the result unless you know what to look for.

Intensity-based conversion is great also for gray-scale images (not just black and white). If you select the dot as a single pixel, the result gets large (one pixel -> single character), so for larger images an area (multiply of font size) is selected instead to preserve the aspect ratio and do not enlarge too much.

How to do it:

1. Evenly divide the image into (gray-scale) pixels or (rectangular) areas **dot**s
2. Compute the intensity of each pixel/area
3. Replace it by character from character map with the closest intensity

As the character `map` you can use any characters, but the result gets better if the character has pixels dispersed evenly along the character area. For starters you can use:

- `char map[10]=" .,:;ox%#@";`

sorted descending and pretend to be linearly distributed.

So if intensity of pixel/area is `i = <0-255>` then the replacement character will be

- `map[(255-i)*10/256];`

If `i==0` then the pixel/area is black, if `i==127` then the pixel/area is gray, and if `i==255` then the pixel/area is white. You can experiment with different characters inside `map[]` ...

Here is an ancient example of mine in C++ and VCL:

```
AnsiString m = " .,:;ox%#@";
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp = new Graphics::TBitmap;
bmp->LoadFromFile("pic.bmp");
bmp->HandleType = bmDIB;
bmp->PixelFormat = pf24bit;

int x, y, i, c, l;
BYTE *p;
AnsiString s, endl;
endl = char(13); endl += char(10);
l = m.Length();
s ="";
for (y=0; y<bmp->Height; y++)
{
    p = (BYTE*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
    for (x=0; x<bmp->Width; x++)
    {
        i  = p[x+x+x+0];
        i += p[x+x+x+1];
        i += p[x+x+x+2];
        i = (i*l)/768;
        s += m[l-i];
    }
    s += endl;
}
mm_log->Lines->Text = s;
mm_log->Lines->SaveToFile("pic.txt");
delete bmp;
```

You need to replace/ignore VCL stuff unless you use the [Borland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland)/[Embarcadero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Technologies) environment.

- `mm_log` is the memo where the text is outputted
- `bmp` is the input bitmap
- `AnsiString` is a VCL type string indexed from 1, not from 0 as `char*`!!!

This is the result: [Slightly NSFW intensity example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HEKa.png)

On the left is ASCII art output (font size 5 pixels), and on the right input image *zoomed* a few times. As you can see, the output is larger pixel -> character. If you use larger areas instead of pixels then the zoom is smaller, but of course the output is less visually pleasing. **This approach is very easy and fast to code/process.**

When you add more advanced things like:

- automated map computations
- automatic pixel/area size selection
- aspect ratio corrections

Then you can process more complex images with better results:

Here is the result in a 1:1 ratio (zoom to see the characters):

[image: Intensity advanced example]

Of course, for area sampling you lose the small details. This is an image of the same size as the first example sampled with areas:

[Slightly NSFW intensity advanced example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDsia.png)

As you can see, this is more suited for bigger images.

**Character fitting (hybrid between shading and solid ASCII art)**

This approach tries to replace area (no more single pixel dots) with character with similar intensity and shape. This leads to better results, even with bigger fonts used in comparison with the previous approach. On the other hand, this approach is a bit slower of course. There are more ways to do this, but the main idea is to compute the difference (distance) between image area (`dot`) and rendered character. You can start with naive sum of the absolute difference between pixels, but that will lead to not very good results because even a one-pixel shift will make the distance big. Instead you can use correlation or different metrics. The overall algorithm is the almost the same as the previous approach:

1. So evenly divide the image to (gray-scale) rectangular areas **dot**'s

   ideally with the same aspect ratio as **rendered** font characters (it will preserve the aspect ratio. Do not forget that characters usually overlap a bit on the x-axis)
2. Compute the intensity of each area (`dot`)
3. Replace it by a character from the character `map` with the closest intensity/shape

**How can we compute the distance between a character and a dot?** That is the hardest part of this approach. While experimenting, I develop this compromise between speed, quality, and simpleness:

1. **Divide character area to zones**

   [image: Zones]

   - Compute a separate intensity for left, right, up, down, and center zone of each character from your conversion alphabet (`map`).
   - Normalize all intensities, so they are independent on area size, `i=(i*256)/(xs*ys)`.
2. **Process the source image in rectangle areas**

   - (with the same aspect ratio as the target font)
   - For each area, compute the intensity in the same manner as in bullet #1
   - Find the closest match from intensities in the conversion alphabet
   - Output the fitted character

This is the result for font size = 7 pixels

[image: Character fitting example]

As you can see, the output is visually pleasing, even with a bigger font size used (the previous approach example was with a 5 pixel font size). The output is roughly the same size as the input image (no zoom). The better results are achieved because the characters are closer to the original image, not only by intensity, but also by overall shape, and therefore you can use larger fonts and still preserve details (up to a point of course).

Here is the complete code for the VCL-based conversion application:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "win_main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"

TForm1 *Form1;
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------


class intensity
{
public:
    char c;                    // Character
    int il, ir, iu ,id, ic;    // Intensity of part: left,right,up,down,center
    intensity() { c=0; reset(); }
    void reset() { il=0; ir=0; iu=0; id=0; ic=0; }

    void compute(DWORD **p,int xs,int ys,int xx,int yy) // p source image, (xs,ys) area size, (xx,yy) area position
    {
        int x0 = xs>>2, y0 = ys>>2;
        int x1 = xs-x0, y1 = ys-y0;
        int x, y, i;
        reset();
        for (y=0; y<ys; y++)
            for (x=0; x<xs; x++)
            {
                i = (p[yy+y][xx+x] & 255);
                if (x<=x0) il+=i;
                if (x>=x1) ir+=i;
                if (y<=x0) iu+=i;
                if (y>=x1) id+=i;

                if ((x>=x0) && (x<=x1) &&
                    (y>=y0) && (y<=y1))

                    ic+=i;
        }

        // Normalize
        i = xs*ys;
        il = (il << 8)/i;
        ir = (ir << 8)/i;
        iu = (iu << 8)/i;
        id = (id << 8)/i;
        ic = (ic << 8)/i;
        }
    };


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnsiString bmp2txt_big(Graphics::TBitmap *bmp,TFont *font) // Character  sized areas
{
    int i, i0, d, d0;
    int xs, ys, xf, yf, x, xx, y, yy;
    DWORD **p = NULL,**q = NULL;    // Bitmap direct pixel access
    Graphics::TBitmap *tmp;        // Temporary bitmap for single character
    AnsiString txt = "";            // Output ASCII art text
    AnsiString eol = "\r\n";        // End of line sequence
    intensity map[97];            // Character map
    intensity gfx;

    // Input image size
    xs = bmp->Width;
    ys = bmp->Height;

    // Output font size
    xf = font->Size;   if (xf<0) xf =- xf;
    yf = font->Height; if (yf<0) yf =- yf;

    for (;;) // Loop to simplify the dynamic allocation error handling
    {
        // Allocate and initialise buffers
        tmp = new Graphics::TBitmap;
        if (tmp==NULL)
            break;

        // Allow 32 bit pixel access as DWORD/int pointer
        tmp->HandleType = bmDIB;    bmp->HandleType = bmDIB;
        tmp->PixelFormat = pf32bit; bmp->PixelFormat = pf32bit;

        // Copy target font properties to tmp
        tmp->Canvas->Font->Assign(font);
        tmp->SetSize(xf, yf);
        tmp->Canvas->Font ->Color = clBlack;
        tmp->Canvas->Pen  ->Color = clWhite;
        tmp->Canvas->Brush->Color = clWhite;
        xf = tmp->Width;
        yf = tmp->Height;

        // Direct pixel access to bitmaps
        p  = new DWORD*[ys];
        if (p  == NULL) break;
        for (y=0; y<ys; y++)
            p[y] = (DWORD*)bmp->ScanLine[y];

        q  = new DWORD*[yf];
        if (q  == NULL) break;
        for (y=0; y<yf; y++)
            q[y] = (DWORD*)tmp->ScanLine[y];

        // Create character map
        for (x=0, d=32; d<128; d++, x++)
        {
            map[x].c = char(DWORD(d));
            // Clear tmp
            tmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0, 0, xf, yf));
            // Render tested character to tmp
            tmp->Canvas->TextOutA(0, 0, map[x].c);

            // Compute intensity
            map[x].compute(q, xf, yf, 0, 0);
        }

        map[x].c = 0;

        // Loop through the image by zoomed character size step
        xf -= xf/3; // Characters are usually overlapping by 1/3
        xs -= xs % xf;
        ys -= ys % yf;
        for (y=0; y<ys; y+=yf, txt += eol)
            for (x=0; x<xs; x+=xf)
            {
                // Compute intensity
                gfx.compute(p, xf, yf, x, y);

                // Find the closest match in map[]
                i0 = 0; d0 = -1;
                for (i=0; map[i].c; i++)
                {
                    d = abs(map[i].il-gfx.il) +
                        abs(map[i].ir-gfx.ir) +
                        abs(map[i].iu-gfx.iu) +
                        abs(map[i].id-gfx.id) +
                        abs(map[i].ic-gfx.ic);

                    if ((d0<0)||(d0>d)) {
                        d0=d; i0=i;
                    }
                }
                // Add fitted character to output
                txt += map[i0].c;
            }
        break;
    }

    // Free buffers
    if (tmp) delete tmp;
    if (p  ) delete[] p;
    return txt;
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnsiString bmp2txt_small(Graphics::TBitmap *bmp)    // pixel sized areas
{
    AnsiString m = " `'.,:;i+o*%&$#@"; // Constant character map
    int x, y, i, c, l;
    BYTE *p;
    AnsiString txt = "", eol = "\r\n";
    l = m.Length();
    bmp->HandleType = bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat = pf32bit;
    for (y=0; y<bmp->Height; y++)
    {
        p = (BYTE*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
        for (x=0; x<bmp->Width; x++)
        {
            i  = p[(x<<2)+0];
            i += p[(x<<2)+1];
            i += p[(x<<2)+2];
            i  = (i*l)/768;
            txt += m[l-i];
        }
        txt += eol;
    }
    return txt;
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void update()
{
    int x0, x1, y0, y1, i, l;
    x0 = bmp->Width;
    y0 = bmp->Height;
    if ((x0<64)||(y0<64)) Form1->mm_txt->Text = bmp2txt_small(bmp);
     else                  Form1->mm_txt->Text = bmp2txt_big  (bmp, Form1->mm_txt->Font);
    Form1->mm_txt->Lines->SaveToFile("pic.txt");
    for (x1 = 0, i = 1, l = Form1->mm_txt->Text.Length();i<=l;i++) if (Form1->mm_txt->Text[i] == 13) { x1 = i-1; break; }
    for (y1=0, i=1, l=Form1->mm_txt->Text.Length();i <= l; i++) if (Form1->mm_txt->Text[i] == 13) y1++;
    x1 *= abs(Form1->mm_txt->Font->Size);
    y1 *= abs(Form1->mm_txt->Font->Height);
    if (y0<y1) y0 = y1; x0 += x1 + 48;
    Form1->ClientWidth = x0;
    Form1->ClientHeight = y0;
    Form1->Caption = AnsiString().sprintf("Picture -> Text (Font %ix%i)", abs(Form1->mm_txt->Font->Size), abs(Form1->mm_txt->Font->Height));
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void draw()
{
    Form1->ptb_gfx->Canvas->Draw(0, 0, bmp);
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void load(AnsiString name)
{
    bmp->LoadFromFile(name);
    bmp->HandleType = bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat = pf32bit;
    Form1->ptb_gfx->Width = bmp->Width;
    Form1->ClientHeight = bmp->Height;
    Form1->ClientWidth = (bmp->Width << 1) + 32;
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
{
    load("pic.bmp");
    update();
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
{
    delete bmp;
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
{
    draw();
}


//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseWheel(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
{
    int s = abs(mm_txt->Font->Size);
    if (WheelDelta<0) s--;
    if (WheelDelta>0) s++;
    mm_txt->Font->Size = s;
    update();
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is simple a form application (`Form1`) with a single `TMemo mm_txt` in it. It loads an image, `"pic.bmp"`, and then according to the resolution, choose which approach to use to convert to text which is saved to `"pic.txt"` and sent to memo to visualize.

For those without VCL, ignore the VCL stuff and replace `AnsiString` with any string type you have, and also the `Graphics::TBitmap` with any bitmap or image class you have at disposal with pixel access capability.

**A very important** note is that this uses the settings of `mm_txt->Font`, so make sure you set:

- `Font->Pitch = fpFixed`
- `Font->Charset = OEM_CHARSET`
- `Font->Name = "System"`

to make this work properly, otherwise the font will not be handled as mono-spaced. The mouse wheel just changes the font size up/down to see results on different font sizes.

**[Notes]**

- See [Word Portraits visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23804827/2521214)
- Use a language with bitmap/file access and text output capabilities
- I strongly recommend to start with the first approach as it is very easy straightforward and simple, and only then move to the second (which can be done as modification of the first, so most of the code stays as is anyway)
- It is a good idea to compute with inverted intensity (black pixels is the maximum value) because the standard text preview is on a white background, hence leading to much better results.
- you can experiment with size, count, and layout of the subdivision zones or use some grid like `3x3` instead.

**Comparison**

Finally here is a comparison between the two approaches on the same input:

[image: Comparison]

The green dot marked images are done with approach **#2** and the red ones with **#1**, all on a six-pixel font size. As you can see on the light bulb image, the shape-sensitive approach is much better (even if the **#1** is done on a 2x zoomed source image).

**Cool application**

While reading today's new questions, I got an idea of a cool application that grabs a selected region of the desktop and continuously feed it to the **ASCIIart** convertor and view the result. After an hour of coding, it's done and I am so satisfied with the result that I simply must have to add it here.

OK the application consists of just two windows. The first master window is basically my old convertor window without the image selection and preview (all the stuff above is in it). It has just the ASCII preview and conversion settings. The second window is an empty form with transparent inside for the grabbing area selection (no functionality whatsoever).

Now on a timer, I just grab the selected area by the selection form, pass it to conversion, and preview the **ASCIIart**.

So you enclose an area you want to convert by the selection window and view the result in master window. It can be a game, viewer, etc. It looks like this:

[image: ASCIIart grabber example]

So now I can watch even videos in **ASCIIart** for fun. Some are really nice :).

[image: Hands]

If you want to try to implement this in **GLSL**, take a look at this:

- [Convert floating-point numbers to decimal digits in GLSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793883/convert-floating-point-numbers-to-decimal-digits-in-glsl/44797902#44797902)

Comment: You did an incredible job here! Thanks! And I love the ASCII censoring!

Comment: A suggestion for improvement: work out directional derivatives, not just intensity.

Comment: @Yakk care to elaborate?

Comment: @tarik either match not only on intensity, but on derivatives: or, band pass enhance edges.  Basically intensity is not the only thing people see: they see gradiants and edges.

Comment: @Yakk the zones subdivision does kind of such thing indirectly. May be even better would be do a handle characters as `3x3` zones and compare the **DCT**s but that would decrease performance a lot I think.

Comment: I was wondering, if you scale-up an image it would blurr, but that wouldn't matter that much when converted to ASCII-art .. is it possible to to scale-up ASCII-art with keeping detail (not to be confused with changing the font-size which change how ASCII-art is rendered) ?

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer Yes you just use smaller area then the font size (until you hit single pixel or 3x3 pixels depending on the method you choose)

Comment: @BradLarson pictures in question converted to links and added SFW comparison image instead (first few nice SFW sketches on Google). btw this can be used on any images but if the background intensity is close to objects the details can get lost

Comment: @Spektre - Cool, thanks. Appreciate the fast response. Wanted to make sure such a helpful answer wouldn't cause any problems with anyone.