# How to generate such graphical console logs?

Tags: javascript, console.log

```
export function bootstrap() {
  console.log(`

████████╗██████╗  █████╗ ███╗   ██╗███████╗██╗████████╗██╗██╗   ██╗███████╗    ██████╗ ███████╗
╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗████╗  ██║██╔════╝██║╚══██╔══╝██║██║   ██║██╔════╝    ██╔══██╗██╔════╝
   ██║   ██████╔╝███████║██╔██╗ ██║███████╗██║   ██║   ██║██║   ██║█████╗      ██████╔╝███████╗
   ██║   ██╔══██╗██╔══██║██║╚██╗██║╚════██║██║   ██║   ██║╚██╗ ██╔╝██╔══╝      ██╔══██╗╚════██║
   ██║   ██║  ██║██║  ██║██║ ╚████║███████║██║   ██║   ██║ ╚████╔╝ ███████╗    ██████╔╝███████║
   ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚══════╝╚═╝   ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═══╝  ╚══════╝    ╚═════╝ ╚══════╝
`)
}
```

How can I generate such console.logs. is there any website?

Comment: maybe have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983648/1447675

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're called ASCII art usually.

This is one of the longest standing websites: https://patorjk.com/software/taag/