# System font does not work with OEM_CHARSET

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, fonts

I created a very simple `c++ win32` application, and I'm trying to draw some text using the following font settings:

```
charset = OEM_CHARSET
pitch = FIXED_PITCH
name = L"System"
```

I create the font like this:

```
CreateFont(16, 0, 0, 0, FW_REGULAR, false, false, false, OEM_CHARSET, OUT_RASTER_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, FIXED_PITCH, L"System");
```

and I draw the text in `WM_PAINT` like this:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

SelectObject(hdc, font);
TextOut(hdc, 100, 200, L"wiw", 3);

EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

However, the text that is drawn is in the `Consolas` font, not the `System` font.
The thing is, if I change `OEM_CHARSET` to `DEFAULT_CHARSET`, then the text is drawn using the correct font `System`.

Here is the text drawn **with** `OEM_CHARSET` (ie not working):
[image: not working example]

Here is the text drawn **without** `OEM_CHARSET` (ie working, but I need `OEM_CHARSET` set):
[image: working example]

The reason I need `OEM_CHARSET` set is because I'm attempting to replicate [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987103/image-to-ascii-art-conversion), and the answer states that `OEM_CHARSET`, `FIXED_PITCH` and `System` are required.

My questions are:

1. Why does `OEM_CHARSET` render `System` font with a different font altogether?
2. What does `OEM_CHARSET` even do? The documentation just states it maps the characters differently, but I'm using plain `ascii`, so why would that matter?
3. Does my version of windows matter? I'm using `Windows 10 x64`.

Comment: You don't need `OEM_CHARSET`. The referenced Q&A states the intended purpose: To get a mono-spaced font.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks! However, if I remove `OEM_CHARSET`, is the font still monospaced? I specified `FIXED_PITCH` so it should be right?

Comment: So long as you pick a font that is mono-spaced (like "Cascadia Mono"). Just don't use "System", it's [a font that nobody uses any more](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050707-00/?p=35013).

Answer (score 0):

The System font is a proportional one, so font mapper has hard time to find `FIXED_PITCH` font with name `System`. Because `FIXED_PITCH` has higher priority than font name, font mapper tries to substitute another one that at least partially meets stated requirements and it chooses some fixed pitch font.

To resolve this, specify name for fixed pitch font e.g. `FixedSys` *, `Terminal` *, `Lucida Console`, `Courier` *, `Courier New` etc. or not specify name at all. Fonts marked with * are raster fonts (bitmapped). Depending on your use case it could be good or bad.

1
I'm not sure how exactly `OEM_CHARSET` plays int this case, but font mapper tries to choose font that covers characters from given charset, so it probably limits suitable font substitutions, and gives you different results.

2
I think in polish locale where default code page is `CP1250`, `OEM_CHARSET` selects `CP852` with more DOS-like charset (e.g. box drawing characters).

3
It could depend on Windows version, but is more affected by installed fonts extending possible font substitutions.

Comment: The system responsible for matching a font against user-supplied requirements is called *"font mapper"*, not *"font manager"*.